# What unicode spaces are equal to letter widths?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to replace some letters of a text (in a non monospace font) with spaces of same width.

Is it possible? How?
Are there any non-monospace fonts that allow this?

I found these [unicode spaces](https://jkorpela.fi/chars/spaces.html), and apparently `U+2002` is an EN SPACE and `U+2003` an EM SPACE.
But the widths don't always match.

```html
<p>the en space looks nice</p>
<p>the e&#x2002; space looks &#x2002;ice</p>

<p>but em space has more width</p>
<p>but e&#x2003; space has &#x2003;ore width</p>
```

And I wonder what spaces should I use for other letters...

I know I could set transparency or color to individual letters. But I wanted to find an easy solution with spaces.

Comment: You can't. You're at the mercy of the fontographers that designed your typefaces.

Comment: You can't do exactly what you require, but could you describe exactly what you need the outcome to be? If it's purely visual then give that character color transparent. If it really has to be 'physically' changed to a space character then use a monospace font.

Comment: @Dai do you know any fonts that allow this? Besides monospace.

Comment: I'd use dummy/placeholder `<span>` elements set to known widths. The end-result might look a bit hideous though, but at least the spacing would be _exact_.

Comment: Note also that, because of kerning, the character before and after is important and will change the space needed.

Comment: @vals I guess that's why there are no spaces with equivalent widths.

Answer (score 1):

Your question was interesting so I thought about the fact that you wanted a real space instead of the missing char, typically for a copy-paste operation. Using CSS pseudo-elements could be a solution because the content of them isn't used for text selection.

The space chars have a fixed width, which is not the case for letters since a **m** is wider than a **i**. I think that **EM space** is 1 em wide and **EN space** is 0.5 em.

So my idea was to replace your char, let's say `m`, by this:

```html
<span class="pseudo-space" data-char="m"><span>&nbsp;</span></span>
```

Yes, this is a lot of HTML and you are asking yourself "why having an inner span?". Well, the problem is that we want the space to have no width and we want the pseudo-element to take this space instead. I also noticed that if you replace the non-breaking space `&nbsp;` by the normal space `&#32;` then you get no space at all when you select the text for a copy-paste.

I came out to this solution:

```css
span.pseudo-space {
  position: relative; /* Child span will be absolute. */
  overflow: hidden; /* Just to avoid a potential scrollbar. */
}
span.pseudo-space > span {
  position: absolute; /* Avoid width calculation on the parent span. */
}
span.pseudo-space::after {
  content: attr(data-char); /* Display the original char. */
  color: transparent;
}

/* Just to have a gray block to see the text aligned. */

blockquote {
  margin: 0.5em 0;
  padding: 1em;
  background: #eee;
  display: inline-block;
}
blockquote p:first-child {
  margin-top: 0;
}
blockquote p:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<blockquote>
  <p>The "n" character will never be the same width as a space character.</p>
  <p>The "<span class="pseudo-space" data-char="n"><span>&nbsp;</span></span>" character will <span class="pseudo-space" data-char="n"><span>&nbsp;</span></span>ever be the same width as a space character.</p>

  <p>The "m" character will never be the same width as a space character.</p>
  <p>The "<span class="pseudo-space" data-char="m"><span>&nbsp;</span></span>" character will never be the sa<span class="pseudo-space" data-char="m"><span>&nbsp;</span></span>e width as a space character.</p>
</blockquote>
```

Try to copy-paste the content of the blockquote and you should normally get the space instead of the hidden char. (Tested on Chrome, Firefox and Edge).

Comment: Thank you for this solution! This is useful if we don't want to include the original letters in a copy/paste operation, or reveal them when the text is selected. I also posted the solution I found so far, which is more convenient if I want to change the individual opacity/color of each letter.

Comment: @FerranMaylinch I tried to reply to your original question which was "*I am trying to replace some letters of a text (in a non monospace font) with spaces of same width.*", not knowing that you wanted to animate the paragraph to make letters appear after each other. Effectively, if your question was more oriented towards what you were trying to achieve, I wouldn't have proposed this pseudo-element solution ;-)

Comment: My question was not complete :) But anyway I am glad that you proposed this solution, because it helps understand the power of CSS pseudo-elements!

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to do something like this.
If I could replace letters with spaces of the same width, it would be much easier. I wouldn't need to play with HTML elements and style.

```js
// Convert letter to spans with opacity:0
const p = document.querySelector("p");
p.innerHTML = p.innerText
  .split("")
  .map(c => `<span class='off'>${c}</span>`)
  .join("");

const letterSpans = p.querySelectorAll('span');

// Create random sequence of indexes
const indexes = Array(letterSpans.length).fill().map((e, i) => i)
indexes.sort((a, b) => 0.5 - Math.random());

// Display letters in the order indicated by `indexes`
function displayLetterAtIndex(i) {
  letterSpans[indexes[i]].classList = "on";
  if (i < letterSpans.length - 1) {
    setTimeout(() => displayLetterAtIndex(i+1), 50);
  }
}
displayLetterAtIndex(0);
```

```css
.on {
  opacity: 1;
}

.off {
  opacity: 0;
}

span {
  transition: opacity 1s linear;
}
```

```html
<p>Letters will appear in a random order</p>
```

Comment: The effect is nice! I also like the JavaScript code which is elegant! I would just personnally remove the style attribute and replace it with a CSS class that you then toggle in JS. The advantage is that you can then change the design in CSS and also use transitions or animations if needed.

Comment: @PatrickJanser I liked your suggestion so I used classes :) For some reason, the first letter appears suddenly, without transition. Maybe you could help me fix that.

Comment: Funny, but I don't seem to have the problem on my computer. Perhaps this could have to do with performance issues and in this case the browser takes some shortcuts for the animation, making it less fluid. You could have a go with Chrome's performance analyser. When I played arround to find the pseudo-class solution I did it on codepen.io. I just added your JS solution that I changed to go into child DOM elements. I also took another approach for the timeout callbacks. Yours is chained and mine is in parrallel: https://codepen.io/patacra/pen/bGoRZEW
It was fun to play arround with your topic!

Comment: @PatrickJanser Awesome! That's exactly what I wanted to do, to find the text nodes recursively :)

Comment: @PatrickJanser Thank you for sharing your solution. I added my (work-in-progress) solution here: https://codepen.io/fmaylinch/pen/WNZZgWL. You can try the different  `indexSorter`, commented in the JS code. I like your solution, playing with random timeouts. In my solution, I play with the order of indexes. I will take ideas from your codepen. To start, I will simplify the `fadeIn` function by using opacity transition.